# NPM office-to-pdf With MeteorJS

Tags: npm, meteor

I created a MeteorJS project with office-to-pdf NPM package. When I convert the .docx to .pdf, I got the following.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/1585844726147.3862/1585844726144.pdf'
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open'
```

The package works fine without MeteorJS.

I also tried to export TMPDIR=/tmp/demo with 777 permission, I got the same error. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing it server side or client side? There should be no reason why it can't work with Meteor

Comment: The package looks unmaintained - last released 3 years ago, no source available. Probably dead

Comment: I'm doing in it on the server side. I was able to get to work by resetting the project.